# Retrieve Pod's definition OR Yaml/Json file using Name

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to retrieve yaml/json definition of the Pods running on the cluster.
Is there any way with the help of kubectl, python client ?

I have tried it using [Python Client](https://kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kubernetes.watch.html) with list_namespaced_pod function for 
watching the stream, But Objects has lot of extra fields with 'None' values.

For example if I create a Busybox Pod, I need the command to retrieve the exact definition used to spawn the pod.

How can I achieve the task ?

Comment: Not sure if i understand true but did you try output of 'kubectl get OBJECT_NAME -o yaml'
like this: kubectl get deployments onos -o yaml

Answer (score 0):

Try using `kubectl get pod POD_NAME -o yaml --export`. The `--export` option will strip the output YAML of any cluster specific information. However, it will create a YAML with lots of fields that are populated by default values since this is what the API server sees. When you make a very simple pod definition and deploy it, you are effectively overwriting default values for optional pod attributes, and populating the non-optional attributes.

Comment: It throws error

```

                                                                           
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'o' in -o

```